# What happens to ApplicationData.LocalSettings while Upgrading WP 8.1 SilverLight to WP 8.1 Universal

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, upgrade

I have a WP 8.1 Silverlight app already in store .  Which uses [ApplicationData.LocalSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx) to save its local settings.

I am planning to migrate this app to Windows 8.1 universal . And then will target to windows 10 .

My question is, what will happen to the values  stored in  `ApplicationData.LocalSettings` while upgrading.  I guess the values will be available in universal because the same api is available there. Can anyone confirm it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've a slightly different setup, but maybe it helps: I have a Windows 8 Universal App and a Windows 10 Universal Windows App. Both share the same local settings on my dev machine. So I would expect the same in your scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is still available for UWP applications:

```
var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
```

1. To save settings:

   ```
   localSettings.Values["exampleSetting"] = "Hello Windows";
   ```
2. To retrieve settings:

   ```
   Object value = localSettings.Values["exampleSetting"];
   ```